# htaccess - only change case of URL if URL does not exist

Tags: .htaccess

I need htaccess to change all characters in url to lower case, but only if URL does not exist on the site. I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This converts the URL to lower case, but it converts all existing URL's also. How to avoid that ?

Comment: Rules look fine, you have old browser cache probably.

Comment: "URL does not exist" - do you mean the URL does not map to a physical file or directory?

Comment: Well also if a category with upper case exists on the site then it should not be concerted - is that not possible to check for ?

Comment: How do you define a "category"?

Comment: Well for example this URL: http://xxxxxx.dk/media/com_akeebabackup/js/Backup.min.js?8cefb508a66ab - I would like not to be concerted to http://xxxxxx.dk/media/com_akeebabackup/js/backup.min.js?8cefb508a66ab - but it is! How to avoid that ?

Comment: Not sure why those RewriteConds at the end are not successfully preventing that from happening. Maybe the path you are assembling there, is not actually correct? Usually the variables REQUEST_FILENAME or REQUEST_URI are used for such "existence" checks. If those don't work either - then I'd suggest you enable some rewrite logging, to see what is going on, in detail. (And make sure you don't get fooled by a cached response from your browser, because of the 301 status code.)

Answer (score 0):

> Well for example this URL: `xxxxxx.dk/media/com_akeebabackup/js/Backup.min.js?8cefb508a66ab` - I would like not to be concerted to `xxxxxx.dk/media/com_akeebabackup/js/backup.min.js?8cefb508a66ab` - but it is!
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f 
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

So, this is presumably a physical file. (You mentioned "category" in an earlier comment, which sounds like something completely different - see below <sup>***1**</sup>)

The "problem" with the second rule (above) is that by the time this rule is processed, the URL-path has already been converted to lowercase, so the second *condition* (that checks that it does not map to a file) is successful and the redirect occurs. (It is this same process that allows the preceding `RewriteRule` directives to recursively convert the URL-path to lowercase... the output of one rule is the input of the next, etc.)

You could instead perform the filesystem check first at the top of the `.htaccess` file and *skip* the rule that converts the URL-path to lowercase. However, on Apache 2.4 (which I assume you are using) then the plethora of `RewriteRule` directives that recursively replaces the uppercase letters are unnecessary, since you can use an Apache expression in a `RewriteCond` directive and use the `tolower()` function directly.

For example, the following would replace your existing directives:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that the captured backreference `%1` already contains the slash prefix, so this should not be included in the *substitution* string.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing and test first with a `302` (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

*Aside:*

<sup>***1**</sup> You mentioned "category" in an earlier comment ("if a category with upper case exists on the site then it should not be concerted"), but did not explain what this was (as your example URL that followed did not appear to be a "category" URL)? However, if this is a Joomla/WordPress/CMS type site that contains "categories" as part of a "virtual" URL then you can not differentiate these URLs in `.htaccess` (without a certain amount of "hardcoding") since what determines whether a URL does (or does not) exist is handled by the backend CMS.